# boolean values to numeric values in R

Tags: boolean, logic, boolean-logic

I'm trying to convert the Awesomness column from a logic to numeric type. When I filter the column I seem to get the output TRUE/FALSE/NA. I've played around with the function as.numeric without luck.

```
yo_jedi <- tribble(
  ~Name,          ~Lightsaber_Color,  ~Affiliation,       ~Age,  ~Midi_Chlorians,  ~Years_of_Training, ~Homeworld,
  "Luke Skywalker",     "Blue",         "Rebel Alliance",  32,   15000,             14,                "Tatooine",
  "Obi-Wan Kenobi",     "Blue",         "Jedi Order",      57,   18000,             40,                 "Stewjon",
  "Yoda",              "Green",         "Jedi Order",      900,  20000,            800,                 "Dagobah",
  "Rey",                "Blue",         "Resistance",      20,    8500,              7,                   "Jakku",
  "Ahsoka Tano",       "White",         "Jedi Order",      32,   12000,             12,                   "Shili",
  "Mace Windu",       "Purple",         "Jedi Order",      53,   15500,             28,              "Haruun Kal",
  "Anakin Skywalker",   "Blue",         "Jedi Order",      22,   16000,             12,                "Tatooine",
  "Padmé Amidala",       "N/A",         "Galactic Senate", 27,   15000,              2,                   "Naboo",
  "Leia Organa",      "Purple",         "Rebel Alliance",  25,   14000,              0,                "Alderaan",
  "Chewbacca",           "N/A",         "Rebel Alliance",  200,      0,              0,                "Kashyyyk"
)
```

```
yo_jedi |> 
  mutate(
    Awesomeness = Years_of_Training / Midi_Chlorians * 10000,
  ) |> 
  arrange(Awesomeness, Age) |> 
  filter(Age > 30) |> 
  distinct(Lightsaber_Color, Affiliation = "Jedi Order", Awesomeness > 15)
```

## A tibble: 6 × 3

Lightsaber_Color Affiliation `Awesomeness > 15`
                   
1 Blue             Jedi Order  FALSE
2 White            Jedi Order  FALSE
3 Purple           Jedi Order  TRUE
4 Blue             Jedi Order  TRUE
5 Green            Jedi Order  TRUE
6 N/A              Jedi Order  NA